# How can I limit how often screenshots are taken for one specific test in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have globally set the number of retries for failing tests to 3. Each time a test fails a screenshot is taken. I have one particular test that loops through a number of scenarios and if the test fails every time more than 100 screenshots are taken. This is too resource heavy. I would like to limit the number of times a screenshot is taken for this test.

How can I configure it so that a screenshot is taken only after 3 retries have been exceeded, but only for this test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the automatic screenshot that you get on test fail, there's not a lot you can do to alter it.

Instead, you can turn it off and roll your own screenshot logic, for example

```js
it('manually handles screenshotOnRunFailure', 
  {screenshotOnRunFailure: false, retries: 1}, // set in cypress.config.js if desired
  () => {
    cy.wrap(true).should('eq', false)          // my failing test
  }
)

afterEach(()=> {
  if (Cypress.currentRetry === Cypress.config('retries')) {  // only on last attempt
    cy.screenshot(Cypress.currentTest.title) 
  }
})
```